# Gaussian quadrature three-point

Tags: numerical-methods

Derive the one and two-point Gaussian quadrature formulas for $$I=\int^1_0xf(x)dx\approx \sum_{j=1}^nw_jf(x_j)$$ with weight function $w(x)=x$.

Which I know how to do and which I attached below
*(I will re-edit this sometime in the future by deleting my attachment and writing it in LaTex).*

**My question is:**

> How can I do this problem when asked of three-point Gaussian quadrature with the weighted function $x^2$ and when $\int^1_0xf(x)dx\approx \sum_{j=1}^3w_jf(x_j)$?

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in my determination of the GQ quadrature points and weights for this case [in this SciComp.SE Answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/8997/651).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should follow the same procedure you have done above.
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f(x)dx & \thickapprox w_{1}f(x_{1})+w_{2}f(x_{2})+w_{3}f(x_{3})
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x)=1\Longrightarrow w_{1}+w_{2}+w_{3} & =\int_{0}^{1}1.x^{2}dx=1/3\\
f(x)=x\Longrightarrow w_{1}x_{1}+w_{2}x_{2}+w_{3}x_{3} & =\int_{0}^{1}x.x^{2}dx=1/4\\
 & \vdots\\
f(x)=x^{5}\Longrightarrow w_{1}x_{1}^{5}+w_{2}x_{2}^{5}+w_{3}x_{3}^{5} & =\int_{0}^{1}x^{5}.x^{2}dx=1/8
\end{align*}
$$
So you have a nonlinear system of equations. You should solve it with a solver.
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}w(x)f(x)dx & \thickapprox \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_{j}f(x_{j})
\end{align*}\qquad (*)
$$

Additionally as i know in $(*)$ the node points $x_i$ are the zeros of the n-th degree orthogonal polynomial on $[a, b]$ with respect to weight function $w(x)$.

Also after some research on google as i understood there are some packages( for example "ORTHPOL") which can give Gauss quadrature rules for arbitrary weight functions.

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolate this for three points? You still have an overdetermined system with 3 points and 4 functions

You could also consider using orthogonal polynomials to construct the quadrature

Comment: I am not following??